# React Native run-windows error microsoft.ui.xaml.winmd not found

Tags: c#, react-native

midlrt : error MIDL1001: [msg]cannot open input file [context]Error opening or processing WinMD d:\Desktop\projects\plenusbusiness\windows\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml.2.3.191129002\lib\uap10.0\microsoft.ui.xaml.winm
d. HRESULT 0x80070003. [D:\Desktop\projects\Example\node_modules\react-native-windows\Microsoft.ReactNative\Microsoft.ReactNative.vcxproj]
D:\Desktop\projects\Example\node_modules\react-native-windows\ReactUWP\Views\cppwinrt\AccessibilityAction.idl(1): error MIDL5157: [msg]An invalid winmd file was specified for import [context]: D:\Desktop\projects\Example\windows\packages\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.3.191129002\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.winmd [D:\Desktop\projects\Example\node_modules\react-native-windows\Microsoft.ReactNative\Microsof
t.ReactNative.vcxproj]

Comment: You might add an actual question, stating what you were attempting to achieve, and how. Just an error dump alone does not make for a good question for itself. Forgive the double pleonasm.

Comment: He tried to run ``npx react-native run-windows`` to start/build a React Native Windows project. I get a similar error. ``× Build failed with message 5>midlrt : error MIDL1001: [msg]cannot open input file [context]Error opening or processing WinMD c:\my project\windows\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml.2.3.191129002\lib\uap10.0\microsoft.ui.xaml.winmd. HRESULT 0x80070003. [C:\my project\node_modules\react-native-windows\Microsoft.ReactNative\Microsoft.ReactNative.vcxproj]. Check your build configuration.``

Comment: Thanks, that's actually actionable 

Comment: Might take a look into the runtime with a debugger a bit later  (js & native, depending on where I end up debugging the JS part)

Comment: I think I've found the problem. The project's path probably should not contain space or special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to fix the error by removing any spaces and special characters from your project's path and I think after this you have to use npm install again before building the project. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to open VS 2019 using the sln inside the /windows folder and rebuild the the project. After that the command "npx react-native run-windows" worked as expected